# Get next index in loop

Tags: groovy

I have:

```
List<Object> list = ((Dao)dao).findAll();
for(int i; i < list.size(); i++) {
    list.getIndex(i);
    list.getIndex(i+1);
}
```

Is this posible?
I'm using the iteration correctly?

Comment: Don't know about Groovy but presume will throw an Exception at `i==list.size()-1` !

Comment: Yes, but is controlled with a try - catch in that moment

Comment: @DavidJara You shouldn't be using `try`...`catch` blocks to work around bad code

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, though to prevent an exception, you should use `for (int i = 0 ; i < list.size() - 1; i++)`.

---

You can use this [`collate`](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/groovy-goodness-collate-list-into-sub.html) to get non-overlapping pairs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].collate(2).each { 
  def (first, second) = it
  println "$first $second" 
}
```

Which will print:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to compare neighbours, you might be better with:

```
for(int i = 1; i < list.size() ; i++) {
 list.getIndex(i - 1)
 list.getIndex(i)
}
```

Or i think you can do something like:

```
list.collate( 2, 1, false ).each { a, b ->
    println "$a $b"
}
```